# GoogleApiClient seems to have no callback for the disconnect() API...?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-api-client

If you invoke GoogleApiClient #connect() you are not actually connected until the onConnected callback handler is invoked.

However, it seems no such "notification" is given for the #disconnect() API call. Am I missing something, or perhaps disconnects are assumed to occur immediately, hence no callback?

I do see an #onConnectionSuspended callback but it doesn't seem to be invoked when you disonnect(), probably is for more exceptional situations.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionSuspended][1] is only called when there is a temporary disconnect caused by a problem, not by an explicit call to `disconnect`.


  [1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `disconnect()` call returns immediately and you can assume that any subsequent calls will fail.  The connection to the service will be broken, but the service may live on for a little while, finishing asynchronous tasks, cleaning up, etc.